# Not Updating Folders Custom Content Type 

Tags: 2007, content-type

Please help me urgent..!

I have the following content types

ShareDoc Document
  Program or Project Folder
  Secure Folder
  Folder

I am creating nested folder in sharepoint document library in my project.
Problem:
I created one folder name is "Test" and content type "Program or Project".If i create a subFolder , the content type of subFolder is "Program or Project".Becuase it is taking default parent content type.But i want to change the content type to "Folder".Please give me solution to reslove it.

Regards,
Shiva Reddy.P

Comment: I am writing code to modify this not at design time , also a work flow is assigned by the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resloved.

**Previous Code:**

Dim CurContentFolder As SPFolder = rootFolder.SubFolders.Add (ObjectsChars.assign_mapchar2objects(folderPathSplit(DocLibCount)))
CurContentFolder.Item(SPBuiltInFieldId.ContentTypeId) = curWeb.ContentTypes("Folder").Id
CurContentFolder.Item.SystemUpdate()

**Modifed Code:**

Dim CurContentFolder As SPFolder = rootFolder.SubFolders.Add(ObjectsChars.assign_mapchar2objects(folderPathSplit(DocLibCount)))
Dim newItem As SPListItem = CurContentFolder.Item
newItem("Content Type") = "Folder"
newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
newItem.SystemUpdate()

Thanks for all to help Me.
Shiva Reddy.P

Answer (score 0):

Laura Rogers has a blog post about using different folder content types to display views, perhaps this may help you in setting up the subFolder's content type...

http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71